# create shortcut with vbs

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

I'm installing a program to 'c:\program files (x86)\myfolder\' and calling a vbs script to create a desktop shortcut.

```
Dim linkObj
Set linkObj = shellObj.CreateShortcut(linkFilePath)

linkObj.WindowStyle = "1"
linkObj.HotKey = linkHotKey
linkObj.Arguments = linkArgs
linkObj.Description = linkDesc
linkObj.TargetPath = linkTarget
linkObj.WorkingDirectory = linkWorkingDir
If (linkIconPath <> "") Then linkObj.IconLocation = linkIconPath
linkObj.Save
```

I'm passing full strings without any environment string, but in the final result linkIconPath is being changed to '%programfiles%\myfolder\myicon.ico', which means that windows explorer (being a 64 bits application) is searching for myicon.ico in 'C:\Program Files\myfolder\myicon.ico' instead of 'c:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder\myicon.ico'

How do I prevent that from happening?
(I do not want to copy the icon files to a separated, non-redirected folder)

Comment: Can you show us what string values are being assigned to each of your variables?

Comment: If `linkIconPath`is being "changed", we don't know that it's occurring in the code you showed us as we can't see anything being assigned to the variable in the first place, as well as any changes that may have been done to it before getting to the code you posted.

Comment: linkIconPath is 'c:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder\myicon.ico'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by transforming the string "c:\Program Files (x86)\myfolder\myicon.icon" into the old dos 8.3 short format before passing it to IconLocation:
'c:\PROGRA~2\myfolder\myicon.ico'

```
set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

folder = "c:\Program Files (x86)"
set fsoFolder = fsObj.GetFolder(folder)
folder = fsoFolder.ShortPath
```

IconLocation will still manipulate the string into '%SystemDrive%\PROGRA~2\myfolder\myicon.ico', but I'm ok with that.